# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

so i trying to make a form with laravel but other than in new version they removed form ! but i can get this running

so here is is :

```
Route::post('/register', function()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user-> u_n = Input::get('u_n');
    $user->save();
    return View::make('thanks')->with('theEmail',$theEmail);
});
```

and my blade :

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'register'))}}

username : {{Form::label('u_n', 'E-Mail Address');}}
{{Form::text('u_n');}}
{{Form::submit('');}}
```

u_n is name of my mysql data base field 
and this is the actual error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`u_n`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sepehr, 2014-12-24 14:32:55, 2014-12-24 14:32:55))
```

Comment: So does your model have `$timestamps` set as true, but the database table doesn't have the appropriate columns?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277955/laravelunknown-column-updated-at

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is happens because Laravel assumes you want to use the `updated_at` and `created_at` timestamps for your models. So it also assumes they exist in the database. You can either create the two columns or disable timestamps for your model by adding

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

[Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps)

By the way: If you're using migrations, adding the timestamp columns is a breeze.

```
Schema::table('table_name', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->timestamps();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i went on and created 2 columns manually and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.

```
     $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();:
```

Then reset your migrations

```
    php artisan migrate:reset
    php artisan migrate
```