# Laravel Unknown Column 'updated_at'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I've just started with Laravel and I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'updated_at' insert into gebruikers (naam, wachtwoord,
>   updated_at, created_at)

I know the error is from the timestamp column when you migrate a table but I'm not using the `updated_at` field. I used to use it when I followed the Laravel tutorial but now that I am making (or attempting to make) my own stuff. I get this error even though I don't use timestamps. I can't seem to find the place where it's being used. This is the code:

**Controller**

```php
public function created()
{
    if (!User::isValidRegister(Input::all())) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(User::$errors);
    }

    // Register the new user or whatever.
    $user = new User;
    $user->naam = Input::get('naam');
    $user->wachtwoord = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();

    return Redirect::to('/users');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('created', 'UserController@created');
```

**Model**

```
public static $rules_register = [
    'naam' => 'unique:gebruikers,naam'
];

public static $errors;
protected $table = 'gebruikers';

public static function isValidRegister($data)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($data, static::$rules_register);

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        return true;
    }

    static::$errors = $validation->messages();

    return false;
}
```

I must be forgetting something... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check your table if you have column **updated_at** !

Comment: @MehdiMaghrooni I dont.

Comment: And that's the problem, you want to access the column which doesn't even exists. You either gotta alter your table to add the one, or simply remove that one.

Comment: @bad_boy Im not even using updated_at anywhere in my code.

Comment: @bad_boy I just had to put the timestamps on false in the model...

Answer (score 657, accepted):

In the model, write the below code;

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

This would work.

Explanation : By default laravel will expect created_at & updated_at column in your table.
By making it to false it will override the default setting.

Comment: @RameshPareek It is stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models): `By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the $timestamps property on your model to false`

Comment: Unless this is for audit purposes, I'm not seeing why this is necessary to begin with, should probably be turned off by default and enabled as an option.

Comment: Interesting that in migrations you have to specify creating timestamps, like so:
`$table->timestamps();`

So in migrations timestamp is off by default, but in models is on by default.

Answer (score 67):

Setting timestamps to false means you are going to lose both created_at and updated_at whereas you could set both of the keys in your model.

**Case 1:**

You have `created_at` column but not update_at you could simply set `updated_at` to false in your model

```
class ABC extends Model {

const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

**Case 2:**

You have both `created_at` and `updated_at` columns but with different column names

You could simply do:

```
class ABC extends Model {

const CREATED_AT = 'name_of_created_at_column';
const UPDATED_AT = 'name_of_updated_at_column';
```

Finally ignoring timestamps completely:

```
class ABC extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Link to laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#timestamps

Comment: this should be the correct answer. Setting timestamps removes both of the fields. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is the correct answer due to the just updated_at field in the error showed in the question.

Comment: This answer is the best one

Comment: When tried setting the UPDATED_AT constant to false, I got "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer" and couldn't find an answer anywhere on how to solve that. Had to use the $timestamps solution in the end and rely on manually setting the values.

Comment: working solution

Answer (score 18):

Nice answer by Alex and Sameer, but maybe just additional info on why is necessary to put

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Timestamps are nicely explained on official [Laravel page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your >tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by >Eloquent, set the  $timestamps property on your model to false.

Answer (score 14):

For those who are using laravel 5 or above must use public modifier other wise it will throw an exception

```
Access level to App\yourModelName::$timestamps must be
public (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)

public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

**First Solution**

If not necessary `created_at` and `updated_at`, please write the below code in the model.

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

**Second Solution**

If you need to use `created_at` and `updated_at` in the future, you can add columns.

Create migration file:

```
php artisan make:migration add_timestamps_fields_to_users_table
```

Edit migration file:

```
class AddTimestampsFieldsToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Run migration:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want the timestamps, but simply forgot to add them in the migration, adding the following to your migration file, will also work:

```php
class AddUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamps(); // <-- Add this to add created_at and updated_at
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to re-run your migration afterwards.

```sh
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

```sh
php artisan migrate
```