# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have this QueryException

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `comentarios` (`NombreUsuario`, `CorreoUsuario`, `TelefonoUsuario`, `Asunto`, `Mensaje`, `FecComentario`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Andres, poc@dw.xom, 124422432, Andres es genial, vffgdf, 2016-11-20 03:34:45, 2016-11-20 03:44:18, 2016-11-20 03:44:18))
```

and this is my sql for laravel 5.1

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        \JuanSapo\ContadorT::create([
            'NombreUsuario' => $request['nombres'],
            'CorreoUsuario' => $request['email'],
            'TelefonoUsuario' => $request['numContacto'],
            'Asunto' => $request['asunto'],
            'Mensaje' => $request['mensaje'],
            'FecComentario' => $request['fecha']

            ]);

            return view('contacto');
    }
```

I can see, i have two dates more just in the end and this look on my sql's mistake,

This is my auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    'model' => JuanSapo\User::class,
    'model' => JuanSapo\ContadorT::class,

    'table' => 'users',
    'table' => 'comentarios',

    'password' => [
        'email'  => 'emails.password',
        'table'  => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

];
```

this is my User.php

```
<?php

namespace JuanSapo;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

This is my contadotT.php

```
<?php

namespace JuanSapo;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class ContadorT extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;


    protected $table = 'comentarios';

    protected $fillable = ['NombreUsuario', 'CorreoUsuario', 'TelefonoUsuario','Asunto','Mensaje','FecComentario'];

    protected $hidden = ['contador'];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277955/laravelunknown-column-updated-at

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `public $timestamps = false;` in your `ContadorT` model class, so Laravel won't add `crated_at` & `update_at` fields in the query

Comment: it was true, 
Thank you